# Django Rest Auth - UID invalid value error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a DRF server, and I've been trying to send a password reset email, using the `PasswordResetForm`.

I receive an email as expected, though when trying to send a reset the password, I receive:

```
{
    "uid": [
        "Invalid value"
    ]
}
```

After some investigation, I've found that in Django's `PasswordResetConfirmSerializer`'s file, there is a conditional import which is responsible for the issue - I'm using `allauth` and so **it imports the wrong `uid_decoder` module** (it works using the other module):

```
# this imports the wrong uid_decoder
if 'allauth' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from allauth.account.forms import default_token_generator
    from allauth.account.utils import url_str_to_user_pk as uid_decoder
else:
    from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator 
    from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode as uid_decoder
```

**Is there a better way to handle the issue than editing the dj_rest_auth file?**

Thanks!

*Email send code, if needed:*

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm


def send_user_invite(email):
    # send invitation to reset password & join the platform
    form_options = {
        "use_https": True,
        "from_email": getattr(settings, "DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL"),
        # "request": request,
        "subject_template_name": "registration/password_reset_subject.txt",
        "email_template_name": "users/invite_with_password_reset.html",
        "extra_email_context": {"reset_base_url": settings.RESET_BASE_URL},
    }
    form = PasswordResetForm(data={"email": email})
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(**form_options)
```

Comment: have you been able to solve this if YES how please

Comment: [a work around](https://gist.github.com/squio/28aadec528bea9302c168744fd0af3b6) I think it is a bug with dj-rest-auth

Comment: Perhaps there is. Posted my workaround as a comment down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround was to write a custom subclass for `ResetPasswordForm`, as follows:

```
# helpers.py
from server.users.forms import SendInviteForm


def send_user_invite(email):
    # send invitation to reset password & join the platform
    form = SendInviteForm(data={"email": email})
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(None)
```

```
from os import path

from allauth.account.forms import (
    EmailAwarePasswordResetTokenGenerator,
    ResetPasswordForm,
)
from allauth.account.utils import user_pk_to_url_str
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import forms as admin_forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _



class SendInviteForm(ResetPasswordForm):
    """
    used to send an invitation to onboard the platform and reset the password
    """

    default_token_generator = EmailAwarePasswordResetTokenGenerator()

    def send_email_invite(self, email, uri, uid, token):
        context = {
            "uri": uri,
            "uid": uid,
            "token": token,
        }
        msg_plain = render_to_string("users/invite_with_password_reset.txt", context)
        msg_html = render_to_string("users/invite_with_password_reset.html", context)
        send_mail(
            "Welcome!",
            msg_plain,
            None,
            [email],
            html_message=msg_html,
        )

    def save(self, request, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        token_generator = kwargs.get("token_generator", self.default_token_generator)
        for user in self.users:
            temp_key = token_generator.make_token(user)
            uri = path.join(settings.CLIENT_BASE_URL, "he/welcome/reset-password")
            self.send_email_invite(email, uri, user_pk_to_url_str(user), temp_key)
        return self.cleaned_data["email"]
```

Comment: This works but I think an easier way is downgrading and using version 2.1.5 which I tried and it works for using the gist I shared earlier to redirect and use the right aid decoder

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but facing the same issue. I'm also being tripped up but that `if 'allauth' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS` statement in `dj_rest_auth`'s `PasswordResetConfirmSerializer` `validate()` method.

My workaround was to subclass `PasswordResetConfirmSerializer` and pick the import statements that work for my setup, in my case use `allauth`'s `default_token_generator` but `django`'s `urlsafe_base64_decode` like so:

```
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetConfirmSerializer as _PasswordResetConfirmSerializer

class PasswordResetConfirmSerializer(_PasswordResetConfirmSerializer):

    # Copy of parent class method with "if 'allauth'" taken out
    def validate(self, attrs):
        from allauth.account.forms import default_token_generator
        from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode as uid_decoder

        # Decode the uidb64 (allauth use base36) to uid to get User object
        try:
            uid = force_str(uid_decoder(attrs['uid']))
            self.user = User._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            raise ValidationError({'uid': [_('Invalid value')]})

        if not default_token_generator.check_token(self.user, attrs['token']):
            raise ValidationError({'token': [_('Invalid value')]})

        self.custom_validation(attrs)
        # Construct SetPasswordForm instance
        self.set_password_form = self.set_password_form_class(
            user=self.user, data=attrs,
        )
        if not self.set_password_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(self.set_password_form.errors)

        return attrs
```

Then in `settings.py` set:

```
REST_AUTH = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.PasswordResetConfirmSerializer'
}
```

A bit messy, but it works.